# Java applet: custom loading animation going crazy?

Tags: java, html, applet, screen, loading

I created a custom loader for my Java applet :

Html Code:

```
<applet [...]
<PARAM name="image" value="pmap_loader.gif"/>
<PARAM name="boxborder" value="false"/>
<PARAM name="centerimage" value="true"/>
<\applet>
```

This works fine, but the gif is going crazy. The loading bar fills itself 1000x per second, while as you can see, the gif has been created properly : https://i.stack.imgur.com/TU2z9.gif

Does someone have an idea how to fix this? I guess the image is constantly refreshing itself or something like that, but I have no idea how I could fix this.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried using JavaDeploy ( http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html )

Comment: When I bring up the properties of that image using FF & go to 'General Properties' I see - *Render Mode: **Quirks mode***.  So I think your confidence in the validity of the image is misplaced.

Comment: Just checked, it is the same in an `ImageIcon`.  Something *is* wrong with the image.